# How to use a multiple worksheets Excel file as Data source in Jaspersoft studio?

Tags: jdbc, dataadapter, jaspersoft-studio

I just started discovering JasperSoft Studio and I'm not really familiar with it's aspects.

I have an excel file with multiple worksheets and I wanted to use it as a data source to create a JasperReport.

Note: I directly use Jasper Studio desktop Ver 6.20.5 (no eclipse IDE or java program)

I tried multiple solutions such as choosing the Excel data adapter as many worksheet that i have (1 Excel data adapter per worksheet by adding the ID of the worksheet in "Sheet selection" section) but I was limited to use only one table.

I'm new to jasper report so I don't know if it is possible to use just one data adapter that includes all the worsheets then selecting the worsheet needed, this way i will be able to do some opérations with SQL language (exemple Select * from [Sheet] )

I saw online another solution : adding apache poi jars in the classpath of the project but did't succeed

Does anyone have a solution or an alternative to this problem please ?